# Como utilizar uma coluna calculada na cláusula WHERE do SQL?

Tags: sql

Tenho a tabela Empregados que possui um campo chamado salário.

Preciso listar somente os empregados que estão abaixo da média de todos os salários de empregados registrados no banco de dados.

Meu comando SQL está assim neste momento:

```
SELECT 
e.IdDepto,
d.NomeDepto,
COUNT(*) as 'Total Empregados',
AVG(e.Salario) AS 'Média'
FROM 
Empregado e
inner JOIN Departamento d ON (d.IdDepto = e.IdDepto)
WHERE
e.Salario < ???
GROUP BY e.IdDepto, d.NomeDepto
```

Minha dúvida está exatamente nestes ???. Como eu posso pegar o valor da coluna calculada chamada 'Média' e utiliza-la como parâmetro para exibir somente os salários dos empregados que estão abaixo de seu valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando uma nova query, onde o resultado dela será apenas a média dos salários.

```
SELECT AVG(Salario) FROM Empregado
```

No query principal ficaria, de forma reduzida

```sql
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Empregado e
WHERE
  e.Salario < (SELECT AVG(Salario) FROM Empregado)
```